# How do I drag and drop images in gtk2.0 in c?

Tags: c, image

I am using a layout container in gtk.I am able to display the images in the container.Now I wish to drag and drop theses images within the container.It seems that since image does not have its own associated window, it is not working.How do I drag and drop  now?Also how do I get the co-ordinates of the images.On using (gdk_window_get_origin) I am getting (0,0) for each image.

A code in c illustrating the drag and drop of images in a layout container would be of great help.